# ¿Cómo obtener la data de una consulta a un api? xamarin

Tags: api, xamarin.forms

Quisiera saber cómo obtener el archivo **json** al consumir un api, lo que intento hacer es el login de la app, y bueno lo que se me ocurrió es que si el StatusCode es igual a OK pase, pero al hacer la consulta siempre regresa OK, pero el valor que manda es diferente

Cuando se ingresan los datos correctos regresa el usuario y la contraseña y cuando no, simplemente regresa un null

¿Cómo pudiera guardar eso en una variable ó comprobarlo?

```
public async Task<bool> checkLogin(string usuario, string password)
        {
            var httpClient = new HttpClient(); 
            var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(MainWebServiceUrl + usuario + "?passwd=" + password);

            if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
```

esto es lo que tenía

Comment: Que tu statusCode sea ok, significa que el servidor responde bien, otra cosa es el contenido de tu respuesta, que es lo que vos necesitas.

Answer (score 0):

Si tu metodo devuelve algo, deberias verificarlo en el content.

```
    public async Task<bool> checkLogin(string usuario, string password)
    {
        var httpClient = new HttpClient(); 
        var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(MainWebServiceUrl + usuario + "?passwd=" + password);

        if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
           if(response.Content != null)
             return true;
           else
            return false;
        }
        
    }
```